# Do the application servers provide SMTP server implementation?

Tags: email, jboss, smtp, mule

I have a requirement to send emails from my Java EE based application to the customers. I am using a JBoss application server.

1. I would like to understand if the application servers has the capability to act as an SMTP server as well.
2. Can we use Mule ESB product to send emails? I guess Mule ESB uses the JavaMail API to send emails.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have the documentation that should clarify your doubts:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/SMTP+Transport+Reference